# How to get the sum of two fields in different table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to get the sum of Purchase_Order.QTY and Purchase_Request.QTY as balance? My problem is there are multiple po_number in Purchase_Order table with has a same counter.

Below is my Tables,

I need to get the total QTY of counter 100001 in purchase_order, so I can get the difference between QTY purchase_order and QTY purchase_request

Table Purchase_Order

```
counter | qty |

100001  | 10  |
100001  | 10  |
100001  | 10  |
100004  | 30  |
```

Table Purchase_Request

```
counter | total_qty |

100001  |     50    |
100002  |     100   |
100003  |     50    |
100004  |     70    |
```

And this my example OUTPUT

OUTPUT

```
counter | total_qty | balance |

100001  |     50    |  20     |
100002  |     100   |  100    |  
100003  |     50    |  50     |
100004  |     70    |  40     |
```

And this is my script,

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");

    $result = $mysqli->query("

    ");
    echo'<table id="tfhover" cellspacing="0" class="tablesorter" style="text-transform:uppercase;" border="1px">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th></th>
    <th>counter</th>
    <th>QTY</th>
    <th>balance</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>';
        echo'<tbody>';
    $i=1;   
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo'<tr>
            <td>'.$i++.'</td>
            <td>'.$row['counter'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['total_qty'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['balance'].'</td>
        </tr>';
       }
    echo "</tbody></table>";

?>
```

Help ?

Comment: what need to be the output from above 2 tables ?

Comment: I need to get the total QTY of counter 100001 in purchase_order, so I can get the difference between QTY purchase_order and QTY purchase_request

Comment: Kindly add your output data for above query.

Comment: from which table you added item column ?

Comment: I edited from purchase_order

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PR.Counter,pr.qty-po.qty as remainingqty FROM Purchase_Request pr LEFT JOIN (Select counter,sum(qty) from Purchase_Order group by counter)po ON pr.Counter=po.Counter
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object, would mine to check the column name if is it correct? I'am newbie in sql pardon me

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option for you.

1. Get all records in Table Purchase_Order `WHERE` counter is = to
   `Purchase_Request.counter`
2. Loop through the results of `QTY` to get a `sum`
3. Compare the sum to `QTY` from the main table to determine if your order can be filled.

This is one option. Another suggestion would be to clean up your database. You might also be able to do SQL joins.

Answer (score 0):

`try this`

```
select a.counter,a.po_number,a.unit_cost,sum(a.qty)-b.qty as ramaining_order_qty
    from table a
    inner join table b on a.counter=b.counter 
    group by a.counter,a.po_number,a.unit_cost,b.qty
```

Comment: i delete some column, what i need is get remaining qty. can you edit your answer? bcoz I'm newbie in sql. :(

Comment: select a.counter,b.qty-sum(a.qty) from table a inner join table b on a.counter= b.counter group by a.counter,b.qty `this should do it`

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object :( ,  this is my table name (purchase_order) column (counter, qty), table name (purchase_request) column (counter, qty)

Comment: it's only echo the counter, why the column qty and balance not showing?

Answer (score 0):

You could join table 1 and 2 on counter number, then use sql to do the calculating

mysql_query("SELECT *, `O.QTY`-`R.QTY` AS `difference` FROM `Purchase_Order AS O LEFT OUTER JOIN Purchase_Request AS R ON O.counter = R.counter");

```
SELECT 
O.id, 
O.QTY,
COALESCE(O.QTY - (SELECT R.QTY 
                 FROM Purchase_Request AS R
                 WHERE O.counter = R.counter)) AS difference 
FROM Purchase_Order AS O;
```

Comment: it doesn't work :( can you check my post, i edited it